# Rails Active Admin: How to add a back button to the dashboard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Seems straight forward. I have searched the webs for about a day now. I dont believe something so simple could be so complicated. Anyway the goal is to add a back button to the Active Admin Dashboard or the navbar or attach the action when you click your email address in the navbar that will take me to another page in my web app that has nothing to do with Active Admin (Lets call it homepage_index_path).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `config.site_title` option. It allows to set URL for the link in top left corner. See [General Configuration](http://www.activeadmin.info/docs/1-general-configuration.html).

Comment: That works, however is there a more elegant way of going about it like adding an extra option?